# Style category post WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins, styles

I want to create a category that all the post in the category will be styled the same way.

Are there WordPress plugins that can easily achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just css. Let's say you create a category called "ken4ward" then just add any styling under the .category-ken4ward class e.g. for styling h5 tags in that category you would use:

```
.category-ken4ward h5 {
   color: red;
 }
```